# How to search for a title in the Vuex store?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I'm expecting to filter by title an array of tasks, by clicking the search button and typing the search input. I'm using Vuex and passing the search param into the mutation via commit to get filter the initial list. But the list isn't rendered. Or is it required by the Vuex to do it through Actions?

**Child component**

```
<template>
    <div class="tasks">
      <input
        type="text"
        v-model="search"
        @keypress.enter="searchTask"
        placeholder="search task"
      />
      <button @click="searchTask" class="btn">Search</button>
      <Task v-for="task in tasks" :key="task.id" :task="task" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      search: '',
    };
  },
  computed: {
    tasks() {
      return this.$store.state.tasks;
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('getTasks').then((data) => console.log(this.tasks));
  },
  methods: {
    searchTask() {
      this.$store.commit('searchTask', this.search);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

**Store**

```
export const state = () => ({
  tasks: [],
});

export const actions = {
  async getTasks(context) {
    const res = await fetch('https://dummyjson.com/todos');
    if (res.ok) {
      let result = await res.json();
      context.commit('setTasks', result.todos);
    }
    return res.ok;
  },
};

export const mutations = {
  setTasks(state, data) {
    state.tasks = data;
  },
  searchTask(state, search) {
    return state.tasks.filter((t) => {
      return t.todo.toLowerCase().includes(search);     // isn't filtering the iniiial array
    });
  },
};
```